# after_create does not update Post attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'm trying to create a callback for a `Post` model. The callback should update the `slug` post attribute. This is the relevant code in `post.rb`:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_slug

  SLUG_FILTER = '/\!?@#$`\'%^&*+=",.()[]{}‘’'

  private

   def set_slug
     self.slug = title.delete(SLUG_FILTER).strip.gsub(/\s+/,'-').downcase
   end
end
```

When I create a `Post` in rails console I get this output:

```rb
irb> author(1).posts.create!(title: 'some post title', markdown: 'test **123**')
=> #<Post id: 25, title: "some post title", markdown: "test **123**", ..., slug: "some-post-title">
irb> Post.find(25)
=> #<Post id: 25, title: "some post title", markdown: "test **123**", ..., slug: nil>
```

It seems that the `slug` attribute is created but then it becomes `nil`. Why is the `slug` attribute `nil` and not `some-post-title`? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.slug =` is just assign `slug` variable so not save to database.
So you should like the below code.

```rb
before_create :set_slug
```

This code assign to `slug` before writing to database.

Answer (score 4):

the after_create callback is trigger after the object was saved. If you modify an attribute it will not be save again.
Before_create should work :)